# May i know how to design the 3 phase converter for BLDC motor with Sinusoidal Commutation?

Tags: matlab, simulink, brush

I have designed a BLDC motor model with Hall Sensors using simulink. It is working perfect with Trapezoidal commutation,with perfect trapezoidal back emf but when i go for sinusoidal commutation, the Hall sensors seem not to detect the electrical angle sequences. I want to know how to generate the three phase input voltages for driving the sinusoidally commutated bldc motor.Presently i am going with sensing the electrical angle using hall sensors and changing the hall state at every 60 degrees and switching the corresponding switches, but this somehow doesn't seem to work. I suppose i have to work on something like using a PWM signal or something. Please help me out.

Answer (score -1):

BLDC motor applications have increased significantly in recent years as energy efficiency, durability, and maintenance-free operation have become increasingly valued. Motor control designers are using the performance characteristics inherent to BLDC motors, giving them a distinct advantage over common ac induction and brushed dc motors used in similar applications.
three phase [power converter](http://www.staticon.ca/industry-applications/motive-power/) can be done as designers can simply choose the appropriate control algorithm and then concentrate on developing and evaluating their own target applications...